# waitfor command not working for delay in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I always get an error for using the "waitfor" command in MySQL
also I checked the MySQL documentation and not written in their documents as well!

is there any update for this command ?

help me please

Comment: There is no waitfor in mysql search for mysql waitfor for possible equivalents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `sleep` command.

With:

```
select current_time();
do sleep(5);
select current_time();
```

I get:

```
--------------
select current_time()
--------------

current_time()
13:23:42
--------------
do sleep(5)
--------------

--------------
select current_time()
--------------

current_time()
13:23:47
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/do.html